# Changing Samba/LDAP password with passwd

Tags: samba, password, pam, ldap

We've installed CentOS Directory Server (389 DS) and have Samba using it as a backend. This works great except that when enabling password syncing in the `smb.conf` it is only synced one way. I could sync the ldap/samba password when using `smbpasswd -a` but not `passwd`. To fix this I added a line to my PAM system-auth settings to update the smb password file when changing my password. Again this works, but I'm getting the following error.

```
Changing password for user testuser1.
Enter login(LDAP) password:
New UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
LDAP password information update failed: Invalid credentials

passwd: Authentication failure
```

This error isn't correct because both the LDAP and Samba passwords change successfully. Does any one have a clue why I'm getting the error at all?

The line I added to PAM is in bold:

`password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3`
**`password    optional      pam_smbpass.so use_authtok use_first_pass`**
`password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok`

My `smb.conf` file has the following:

```
[global]
workgroup = MyGroup
security = user
passdb backend = ldapsam:ldaps://192.168.124.89/
ldap admin dn = cn=Directory Manager
ldap suffix = dc=example,dc=com
ldap user suffix = ou=People
ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
ldap passwd sync = yes
ldap delete dn = no
wins support = yes
```

As I stated previously, everything is working as it should. I just don't want users freaking out when they see that nasty error message and I want it to go away.

Answer (score 1):

(yes, 7 years later, and hopefully it was resolved earlier - this is for current and future reference) smbpasswd can handle LDAP passwd syncing, re:

-w / -W switches, from man page on samba.org website:

> -w password
> This parameter is only available if Samba has been compiled with LDAP
> support. The -w switch is used to specify the password to be used with the
> ldap admin dn. Note that the password is stored in the secrets.tdb and is
> keyed off of the admin's DN. This means that if the value of ldap admin dn
> ever changes, the password will need to be manually updated as well.
>
> -W
> NOTE: This option is same as "-w" except that the password should be entered > using stdin.
>
> This parameter is only available if Samba has been compiled with LDAP
> support. The -W switch is used to specify the password to be used with the
> ldap admin dn. Note that the password is stored in the secrets.tdb and is
> keyed off of the admin's DN. This means that if the value of ldap admin dn
> ever changes, the password will need to be manually updated as well.